# react-zoom-pan-pinch: Hot to set size of the TransformWrapper based on space available for the component, not based on size of the image?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use `react-zoom-pan-pinch` library, but I have a problem setting up the initial size of the component.

My image is very wide.

If I run my app it creates an area where I can slide the image with the same aspect ratio as my image. The area is just a very short rectangle with a lot of space underneath the screen.

I'd prefer to take the entire space of the screen with the right side of the image being outside.

Setting the initial scale doesn't help. It just zooms in the same short rectangle.

Is there any way to set up the initial size of the working area?